# Dynamically and completely fill a div with placeholder text in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to Fill a div with placeholder text.

I have a div that is 100% width+height.  Due to many form factors this height and width will be changing based on the users resolution.  How can i dynamically fill that div with lorem ipsum.  Also how would i recalculate if window sizes changes? *I know i could manually do this with copy paste and overflow hidden but I would rather achieve this in javascript*

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h54tP/)

**css**

```
    html,body {
        /*background:#edecec;*/
        height: 100%;
    }
    .block-text{
        text-align: justify;
        font-size: 8px;
        font-color: rgba(88,89,91, 1);
        font-family: georgia;

        line-height: 7px;
    }
```

**html**

```
    <div class="block-text">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore, eius, ab, molestiae praesentium hic quia quaerat culpa quas consectetur dolor veritatis vel voluptas minus laborum minima quis dolorum necessitatibus tempora.
        </p>

    </div>
```

Comment: Quick guess I'm going to test: Have a child element inside .block-text, fill that child element in every step and check wether it's height has become bigger than that of the parent, then break. Would that be something you could work with?

Comment: I'd create an offscreen (visible, but not onscreen to the user) copy of the div and keep adding text to it until it did not exceed the dimensions of the visible div.  Then copy the contents over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/h54tP/1/

```
var bool = true;
var maxHeight = $('.block-text').height();


do {
    $('.container').append("<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.   Tempore, eius, ab, molestiae praesentium hic quia quaerat culpa quas consectetur dolor veritatis vel voluptas minus laborum minima quis dolorum necessitatibus tempora. </p>");
    if ($('.container').height() > maxHeight) bool = false;
} while (bool);
```

Here, as described in my comment. One wrapping element insinde your text box, the block-text set to 100% height and a small while loop do the trick.

Small note: This will not do anything when the window is resized. For that, however, you could just call that entire code inside a window-size-change function.

Also, this allows the text to be slightly larger than the screen. If you want it slightly smaller instead, just do

```
$('.container').children().last().hide();
```

in the "if"-clause.

Comment: what if the window size changes? what would be the best way to detect and redo

Comment: Put the entire thing inside a $(window).resize(function() {}); :)

Or, most likely, put it inside a named function that is called once on document ready and then on $(window).resize().

Answer (score 0):

I realize you wanted to solve this with javascript, but have you considered using css psuedo-elements with `content`? If this is just for placeholder text as you develop I think it will do what you want without having to add a bunch of javascript and fiddle with resize events.

```
.block-text>p:after { 
    content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore, eius, ab, molestiae praesentium hic quia quaerat culpa quas consectetur dolor veritatis vel voluptas minus laborum minima quis dolorum necessitatibus tempora.';
}
```